# How to add a label to a voltmeter in circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

What's the simplest way to add a label to a voltmeter and a ammeter?

I tried the obvious:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin {circuitikz}[scale=2]
      \draw (0,0)
      to[V,v=$V$] (0,1)
      to[generic=$R_1$] (0,2)
      to[ammeter=$A_1$] (2,2)
      to[voltmeter=$V_1$] (2,0)
      to[short] (0,0);
      \draw (2,2)
      to[short] (4,2)
      to[generic=$R_2$] (4,0)
      to[short] (2,0);
\end {circuitikz}
\caption{caption...}
\label{fig:circuit-1}
\end{figure}
```

But it simply ignore my labels on the voltmeter and ammeter.

I'm importing like this (in case it makes any difference):

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[american voltages]{circuitikz}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the standard TikZ option `label` to add a label to the voltmeter and amperemeter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[american voltages]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[scale=2]
      \draw (0,0)
      to[V,v=$V$] (0,1)
      to[generic=$R_1$] (0,2)
      to[ammeter,label=$A_1$] (2,2)
      to[voltmeter,label=$V_1$] (2,0)
      to[short] (0,0);
      \draw (2,2)
      to[short] (4,2)
      to[generic=$R_2$] (4,0)
      to[short] (2,0);
\end {circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]