# Voltmeter in Latex Tikz circuit diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, diagrams, texstudio

I am working on a circuit using Tikz package in Latex. How do I get a symbol for a voltmeter like this picture:

[image]

I am using

```latex
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
```

and for another diagram I have defined the following symbols

```latex
\tikzset{circuit declare symbol = var voltmeter}
\tikzset{set var voltmeter graphic={draw,generic circle IEC,minimum size=5mm,info=center:V}}
\tikzset{circuit declare symbol = var ammeter}
\tikzset{set var ammeter graphic={draw,generic circle IEC,minimum size=5mm,info=center:A}}
```

so I think I have to define a second symbol. (I only need help with the symbol, the other things I am able to manage.)

**Thank you in advice!**

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE...

Comment: Thank you @MadyYuvi

Comment: Have you checked the documentation, and gone to detexify?

Comment: detexify is really practically (I did not know the tool - but bookmarked it) and I have searched the internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[american voltages]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[scale=2]
      \draw (0,0)
      to[voltmeter,label={}] (2,0);
\end {circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Can I use this inside a `tikzpicture` environment?

Comment: Please check https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/374568/how-to-add-a-label-to-a-voltmeter-in-circuitikz

Comment: Yes --- but notice that `circuitikz` is not completely compatible with the Ti*k*Z `circuits.*` library, see the manual, section 1.6. My personal advice is to choose one or the other, they do not mix very well. And @MadyYuvi, you should specify a voltage convention when using `circuitikz` (see manual, 4.2). Recent manual here: http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz/doc/circuitikzmanual.pdf

Comment: Better to refer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42802/circuitikz-symbols-in-tikz-circuit-library

Comment: @Rmano Thanks for your notification as well as for the recent manual...

Comment: The main difference between the tikz circuit library and circuitikz is that the tikz versions get larger if you add text to the node {}.